# Работа с icq

Tags: python, icq

Нужно сделать программу чат на icq. Есть какие-нибудь библиотеки для работы напрямую с icq (желательно с русскими manual'ами)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свое время помогла вот эта статья [ICQ бот на Python](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/python/111263/).